# GPIO pin already exist GPIO 1 error

Tags: raspbian, gpio, java

I am working on raspberry pi to blink the LED using java.
Its working fine for the first time and it giving this error if I try to run for next time.

```
            GpioController gpioController = GpioFactory.getInstance();
            // Initialize the GPIO pin
            final GpioPinDigitalOutput pin = gpioController
                    .provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01, "MyLED",
                            PinState.HIGH);

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            pin.low();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            pin.toggle();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            pin.toggle();


            gpioController.shutdown();
```

I got the folowing error:

> com.pi4j.io.gpio.exception.GpioPinExistsException: This GPIO pin
>   already exists: GPIO 1
>   com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.provisionPin(GpioControllerImpl.java:50‌​7)
>   com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.provisionDigitalOutputPin(GpioControlle‌​rImpl.java:645)
>   com.pi4j.io.gpio.impl.GpioControllerImpl.provisionDigitalOutputPin(GpioControlle‌​rImpl.java:672)

Comment: are you running java with sudo? and is this Raspbian?

Comment: yes I am running in root and i am using Raspbian

Answer (score 1):

After you call .shutdown() add a line in order to unProvision your pin.

```
gpio.shutdown(); 
gpio.unProvisionPin(pin);
```

This will release pi4j's internal reference and allow you to reprovision it later.

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425918/this-gpio-pin-already-exists-gpio-1-exception-on-second-time